# gcm push messages are not received

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM for android, a sample code given on androidhive.com.I am able to store data in a database but it is not not able to push data. I am new to this code. so please help me the same. My connection java file and corresponding php file along with the logcat messages is shown below---

Error log-

```
11-07 16:55:42.306: E/Trace(1025): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
11-07 16:55:43.146: D/libEGL(1025): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
11-07 16:55:43.166: D/(1025): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a1193e0, tid 1025
11-07 16:55:43.188: D/libEGL(1025): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
11-07 16:55:43.196: D/libEGL(1025): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
11-07 16:55:43.337: W/EGL_emulation(1025): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 16:55:43.366: D/OpenGLRenderer(1025): Enabling debug mode 0
11-07 16:56:00.818: W/EGL_emulation(1025): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 16:56:04.207: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1025): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-07 16:56:04.207: E/SpannableStringBuilder(1025): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
11-07 16:56:21.786: W/EGL_emulation(1025): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 16:56:35.676: D/dalvikvm(1025): GC_CONCURRENT freed 238K, 4% free 8207K/8519K, paused 109ms+131ms, total 355ms
11-07 16:56:35.766: D/GCMRegistrar(1025): resetting backoff for com.androidhive.pushnotifications
11-07 16:56:35.806: V/GCMRegistrar(1025): Registering app com.androidhive.pushnotifications of senders 706448096441
11-07 16:56:35.886: I/Choreographer(1025): Skipped 34 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
11-07 16:56:36.052: W/EGL_emulation(1025): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
11-07 16:56:37.826: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(1025): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
11-07 16:56:37.826: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(1025): GCM IntentService class: com.androidhive.pushnotifications.GCMIntentService
11-07 16:56:37.846: V/GCMBaseIntentService(1025): Acquiring wakelock
11-07 16:56:37.876: V/GCMBaseIntentService(1025): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-706448096441-1
11-07 16:56:37.896: E/GCMRegistrar(1025): internal error: retry receiver class not set yet
11-07 16:56:37.896: V/GCMRegistrar(1025): Registering receiver
11-07 16:56:37.906: D/GCMBaseIntentService(1025): handleRegistration: registrationId = APA91bG-OslPbDcT_9iy0QTP7e_4ih9q95m6fyZJ4geYx1JojDhjmGUTy7aCvVMAq9vLXo31Kh5uP6YpenVc1zDOavhrX1gyayQAXevq8j1T0t1lf88Qm3ohz5mNQ7iC7kY52FG1hD8pgH5aSMGqb55xNGvCIuuFSbIJ3wmiGkpzHhYH2WEp-Q4, error = null, unregistered = null
11-07 16:56:37.906: D/GCMRegistrar(1025): resetting backoff for com.androidhive.pushnotifications
11-07 16:56:37.946: V/GCMRegistrar(1025): Saving regId on app version 1
11-07 16:56:37.978: I/GCMIntentService(1025): Device registered: regId = APA91bG-OslPbDcT_9iy0QTP7e_4ih9q95m6fyZJ4geYx1JojDhjmGUTy7aCvVMAq9vLXo31Kh5uP6YpenVc1zDOavhrX1gyayQAXevq8j1T0t1lf88Qm3ohz5mNQ7iC7kY52FG1hD8pgH5aSMGqb55xNGvCIuuFSbIJ3wmiGkpzHhYH2WEp-Q4
11-07 16:56:38.016: D/NAME(1025): radha
11-07 16:56:38.016: I/AndroidHive GCM(1025): registering device (regId = APA91bG-OslPbDcT_9iy0QTP7e_4ih9q95m6fyZJ4geYx1JojDhjmGUTy7aCvVMAq9vLXo31Kh5uP6YpenVc1zDOavhrX1gyayQAXevq8j1T0t1lf88Qm3ohz5mNQ7iC7kY52FG1hD8pgH5aSMGqb55xNGvCIuuFSbIJ3wmiGkpzHhYH2WEp-Q4)
11-07 16:56:38.016: D/AndroidHive GCM(1025): Attempt #1 to register
11-07 16:56:38.056: V/AndroidHive GCM(1025): Posting 'email=bhawna2909@gmail.com&regId=APA91bG-OslPbDcT_9iy0QTP7e_4ih9q95m6fyZJ4geYx1JojDhjmGUTy7aCvVMAq9vLXo31Kh5uP6YpenVc1zDOavhrX1gyayQAXevq8j1T0t1lf88Qm3ohz5mNQ7iC7kY52FG1hD8pgH5aSMGqb55xNGvCIuuFSbIJ3wmiGkpzHhYH2WEp-Q4&name=radha' to http://10.0.2.2/gcm_server_php/register.php
11-07 16:56:38.056: E/URL(1025): > http://10.0.2.2/gcm_server_php/register.php
11-07 16:56:39.057: V/GCMRegistrar(1025): Setting registeredOnServer status as true until 2012-11-14 16:56:39.057
11-07 16:56:39.166: V/GCMBaseIntentService(1025): Releasing wakelock
```

Java file--

```
package com.androidhive.pushnotifications;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public final class CommonUtilities {

    // give your server registration url here
    static final String SERVER_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/gcm_server_php/register.php"; 

    // Google project id
    static final String SENDER_ID = "706448096441"; 

    /**
     * Tag used on log messages.
     */
    static final String TAG = "AndroidHive GCM";

    static final String DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION =
            "com.androidhive.pushnotifications.DISPLAY_MESSAGE";

    static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";

    /**
     * Notifies UI to display a message.
     * <p>
     * This method is defined in the common helper because it's used both by
     * the UI and the background service.
     *
     * @param context application's context.
     * @param message message to be displayed.
     */
    static void displayMessage(Context context, String message) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
}
```

PHP file--

```
<?php


// response json


$json = array();


/**

* Registering a user device

* Store reg id in users table

*/

if (isset($_POST["name"]) && isset($_POST["email"]) && isset($_POST["regId"]))
 {
    $name = $_POST["name"];

   $email = $_POST["email"];

 $gcm_regid = $_POST["regId"]; 
// GCM Registration ID

// Store user details in db

include_once './db_functions.php';

    include_once './GCM.php';


    $db = new DB_Functions();

   $gcm = new GCM();


    $res = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $gcm_regid);


    $registatoin_ids = array($gcm_regid);

    $message = array("product" => "shirt");


    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);


    echo $result;
}
 else {

   // user details missing

}

?>
```

Comment: Assuming you don't end up in the php's else braces, what does the echoed $result show? Do you get a multicast in a response like the dev docs show:{"multicast_id":6782339717028231855,"success":0,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0," ...etc

Comment: No, it is not showing multicast..

Comment: What does the echo $result show?

Comment: we have removed the echo $result, and now it is not showing any error but the push notification is not received

Comment: You need to put it back. The first step is to find out whether your message went OK from your PHP page to the GCM server. After you establish that, you can investigate whether the stage from GCM server to your device is working.

Comment: please mention step by step that how to check whether the msg is OK from your PHP page to the GCM server.

Comment: You should have a multicast id returned in the response. That's all from me now,  good luck

Comment: when i send message from my browser, i get the success message on my browser that message has been sent( {"multicast_id":7521567298780498395,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1363091749270815%0bbad40df9fd7ecd"}]} ). but couldn't get that message on device.

Answer (score 1):

I too tried the tutorial of android hive but it didn't worked then i did some more google and find this which worked for me.

http://androidexample.com/Android_Push_Notifications_using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=119&aaid=139